# Can RNNs, especially LSTMs be used to detect anomalies in time series?

Tags: time-series, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, anomaly-detection

I have only very rudimentary knowledge of RNNs and LSTMs. My question is whether it is possible to use LSTMs to learn from many time series what is "ordinary" behavior and then for a new time series to compute the probability of it belonging to the same population as the training data, thus deciding whether it is anomalous or not.